# Create two indexes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm

I have this document Scheme: 
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="users") *
 */
class Markers
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Float
     */
    protected $lat;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Float
     */
    protected $lng;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $title;
}
```

What I want is having index on $title field and $lat and $lng 
how do you suggest I should work this out ? 
Do I have to tell the document that these fields are indexes or , running the command in Mongo shell is sufficient ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can define indexes in Mongo shell and make it independent from code implementation. Your database would be accessible from different systems and mantain consistency in its administration.

¿Have you considered the use of geospacial indexes for `lng` and `lat`?

Comment: That's what Im working on right now , but I don't know how to add a new field that has two subfields lat and lng ..

Comment: You can use `collection` for numerically indexed arrays and `hash` for associative arrays.

Comment: More details please ?

Comment: You can have a `$location` with annotation `@MongoDB\Array` and value `array( $lng, $lat )` or with annotation `@MongoDB\Hash` and value `array( "lng" => $lng, "lat" => $lat )`.